# Lenovo Yoga 500-14ISK orientation not working

Tags: lenovo, orientation

I have installed iio-sensor-proxy and trying to make accelerometer to work but without luck. Running monitor-sensor in terminal, I get below

```
Waiting for iio-sensor-proxy to appear
+++ iio-sensor-proxy appeared
=== Has accelerometer (orientation: undefined)
=== No ambient light sensor
```

Kernel 4.10.2-041002-generic
Ubuntu 16.10 
Gnome Shell 3.20.4

I tried to suspend as it was suggest in other fora but orientation remains undefined. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I have a Dell touchscreen laptop, not Yoga. Auto-orientation works out of the box on it with Gnome. Are you aware of this option?   http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206479/what-is-the-icon-between-settings-and-lock-screen-in-gnome3

Comment: I have tried both options with this button, but still the accelerometer has undefined orientation.

Comment: I assume you checked the rotation lock button on the side of the laptop. You may want to look through the BIOS/UEFI to see if auto-rotation is disabled there. You may also want to try booting a live USB or other operating system to see if it is an Ubuntu bug. Something like a live Antergos or Fedora may be a good choice for live USB testing because it is a later kernel.

Comment: I have checked the rotation lock button, I can see the pop up that screen rotation is unlocked, but it doesn't rotate. I haven't find an autorotation option in BIOS to be honest, but there is a new BIOS update that I have to find a way to install. No windows partition in my setup and no bios bootable CD for my BIOS. I am using the latest 4.10.3 kernel, I will try with a Fedora live USB as well.

Comment: If you run out of options, I can post about creating a launcher for an `xrandr` script. It is manual, requires being tapped (instead of auto rotate), but it would be better than nothing.

Comment: I am using spin currently [link](https://github.com/wdbm/spin) as an alternative and works ok, but I have read that there are many users reporting orientation works, hence I am trying to fix mine. If there is a BIOS issue, will try to update on the next days

Answer (score 0):

```
watch -n 0.1 cat '/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device'*/*raw*
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/3sk5tp/autorotation_issues_plus_a_workaround/

Comment: If the link will be gone some day, there will be no explanation left. Please add some words to your answer.